# Recycler view is crashing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

App crashing when I use recyclerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

<include layout="@layout/app_bar_issuehome" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_issuehome"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_issuehome_drawer" />
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    />
```

Error text:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1' Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Answer (score 0):

Did you add

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
```

to dependencies {} in your app build.gradle?

Comment: if i add throws an error.Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Answer (score 0):

Did you include

```
com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1
```

In your gradle script?